# Review this map of B'rachaspace!

Tags: blessing

[Inspired by [this site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), this question is a solicitation for review of a product, copied below. Scale is not intended to be significant.]

1. Is this set-theoretic representation of categories of *b'rachos* accurate?
2. Are there any internal inconsistencies?
3. Is it missing any important categories?
4. Are there any counterexamples?
5. Is it legible?

[image: טבלא לסוגי ברכות]

Comment: Is the inclusion of a "mi'deoraitah" space enough to make it clear the rest is "mi'derabanan"? (assuming that is the case)

Comment: @ArielAllon I am troubled by that as well. Similarly with _aruka_ as !_k'tzara_. Is there a good way to represent those clearly? It was supposed to be so easy. . .

Comment: If you have a legend (as suggested in my answer), you can indicate _mid'oraysa_ with a pattern and write "(the rest is _mid'rabanan_)", perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

- Re 5, legibility: It's not clear which area is denoted *rishona*. Similarly, the notation for *b'racha k'tzara*, to signify that it covers the large upper central rectangle, is not neat, at best, and not clear, at worst. I think perhaps put the words on the side in a legend and simply have overlapping colors and/or patterns for the different types of *b'racha*.
  Also, for clarity, avoid non-convex areas (which is what *rishona* and *mid'rabanan* now are). To that end, the *acharona* box can have its left end flush with the left end of the outer box and its right end flush with the right end of the *hashevach* box, and the *mid'oraysa* box can have the same width as the outer box. Every area of interest would then be convex except *rishona*, which would be a non-convex hexagon (it's currently a non-convex octagon): still not ideal, but better IMO.
- You seem to be missing most of the *b'rachos* found in *sh'mone esre*.

Comment: thanks for the review. Re the _b'racha k'tzara_ rectangle, if it were colored or hatched, it could appear that it was the extension of _nehenin_ and _rishona_ as well. Is there a way to avoid that? And speaking of those two, I believe they are fully overlapping sets. What would you recommend for _Mid'rabanan_?

Comment: @WAF, re a way to avoid: Yes: have a legend. One color or pattern will clearly be for _hanehenin_ and one clearly for _k'tzara_.

Comment: Re _sh'mone esre_, I was mentally including them in _shevach_. Is that too simplistic? Too wrong?

Comment: @WAF, I thought _shevach_ describes the first three _b'rachos_ of _sh'mone esre_, _bakasha_ the next thirteen, and _hodaa_ the last three. Or is that categorization scheme somehow independent of the one you're using?

Comment: @WAF, re _rishona_ (commenting on your comment of 2011-07-12 18:59:12Z): Ah, I thought by _rishona_ you meant everything that's not _acharona_. Dumb of me, actually. So it's fine shape-wise. And so would _mid'rabanan_ be, if you expand the boxes I mention expanding.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. It's almost as if you've done this before. As far as _shevach_ I think it is an independent system, specifically for describing parts of _18_, all of which is basically included in _shevach_. I could be wrong about that, but for partial justification of this terminology, _b'rachos_ of _hoda'a_ are often included in the broad category of _shevach_ when discussing them outside the context of _sh'mone esre_.

Comment: @WAF, what about _birchos k'rias sh'ma_, _hamapil_, _birchos hashachar_ (aside from _birchos hatora_)? Are those also _shevach_, then?

Comment: _Birchos k'ri'as sh'ma_ could qualify as _birchos hamitzva_. Most of the _birchos hashachar_ are _shevach_ since they are of the form "בא"י העושה פלוני". I think the same can be said of _hamapil_ as well.

Comment: Borei Nefashot is a bracha achrona that is ketzara, ie it doesn't have a chatima according to our minhag. You indicate that all brachot achronot are aruka.

Comment: @DoubleAA, this seems to be a comment on the 'map' posted in the question, so would be best posted as a comment on the question or (since it answers the question's parts 1 and 4) as an answer.